# Margin does not create room between two child elements but padding does

Tags: html, css

Looking at the box-model the margin is the distance outside the element box (outside boarder), whereas padding is between the content and the boarder.

Say I have two child-elements `inner-top` and `inner-bottom` both conatined in `outer` e.g

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner-top">
        <img src = "some_image_url">
    </div>

    <div class="inner-bottom">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```css
img{
    height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.outer{
    background-color:rgb(53, 179, 80);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.inner-top{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:rgb(49, 36, 170);
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* this does not create any room but does with padding*/

}

.inner-bottom{
    background-color:crimson;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0
}
```

I want to have say 10px of room between the `inner-top` and `inner-bottom`. Since it is two distinct elements I would assume that we should use `margin-bottom` in `inner-top` (because we need room **after* `inner-top`) but doing so creates no room. Setting `padding-bottom=10px` creates the room. Why is that? Why isn't it margin here, since it is the distance between `inner-top` and `inner-bottom`? In case it does have an impact I'm importing bootstrap4 aswell.

Comment: You used `position:absolute` for the `.inner-bottom` element, so you are leaving the realm of normal layout flow, where margins would apply as expected. Absolute positioning is a whole different ball game, than layouting within the “flow”.

Comment: But that is on `inner-bottom` - the margin/padding is on `inner-top`

Comment: Yes, but margins between elements only apply, when _both_ elements are in normal flow.

Comment: aah.. thats a "gotcha" I didnt knew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just remove "position: absolute" and "bottom: 0" from inner-bottom class and that way is working for me.

but if you never heard for flex this maybe is the moment you been waiting for :) here is the solution which is maybe better:

```
img{
    height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.outer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:rgb(53, 179, 80);
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.inner-top{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:rgb(49, 36, 170);
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; //margin is working now

}

.inner-bottom{
    background-color:crimson;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the position of `.inner-bottom` affects the margin on `inner-top`  - but removing the bomtom and position worked!

Comment: Short question; for some reason, the `margin-top` affects the margin from `outer` in `body` and not the margin of `inner-top` to `outer`. How come?

Comment: The position of inner-bottom does not affect the margin of the inner top. position absolute makes that element not dependent of an entire container. and it behaves as usual until you tring to use some of the "top,bottom, left, right" property.

short question answer:
There are a couple of ways to prevent it from happening. If the parent has a top border or top padding, the child’s top margin will have something to ‘push’ against and not escape.